# Looking for suggestions about tracking system on Android device

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have develop an Android app, this app through a Apache Client send latitude and longitude to a web service. In the moment I receive the coordinates,  I store the data received on a database. I show this data later on Google Maps with markers.
Rigth now my idea will be to improve my App, but I don´t have seen yet clearly the way.  The main idea will be store the track data on mobile device and send to the server when I stop app. (The idea is "save" the track data with My Tracks app, and send to my server, I wanna show the tracks on Google Maps)
Doubts:

- How to store data, KML, KMZ? Any other better choice?
- Is a good idea to save KML or KMZ on database? or it´ll be better choice use Fusion Tables?

Thanks in advance, any suggestion will be really appreciatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you store the latitude and longitude in the DB of your choice, and then use the google maps api to set up your markers.

Placing  your markers with the google api is really easy:

https://developers.google.com/maps/

You can even create flightplans, and add markers for specific position reports.

Just save to database, and then with the server side of your choice, create the js with the proper latlng coordinates.

Comment: I have done finally on that way, and works perfectly. Now I want to show just marker for a specific position, I´m working on that.

Comment: You should accept this as the right answer if it meets your requirements. Noone wants to keep answering your questions if you never accept the correct answer

Comment: Sorry about don´t remenber to check the answer as the correct one.